# How can I optimize this Slayer?

Tags: dnd-4e, optimization

I am Creating a 5th level Charge Happy Slayer. Should I choose to do an extra 1d8+3 damage on each charge or knock the enemy prone on every attack? Our party is Cleric, Paladin, Ranger, Rogue & Slayer(me).  Normally I would go with the extra damage, but considering no controller and 2 other strikers, I was thinking at-will proning might be usefull...Opinions?

```
====== Created Using Wizards of the Coast D&D Character Builder ======
SlashWorth, level 5
Bugbear, Fighter (Slayer)
Auspicious Birth (Auspicious Birth Benefit)
Theme: Ironwrought

FINAL ABILITY SCORES
STR 20, CON 11, DEX 18, INT 8, WIS 10, CHA 12

STARTING ABILITY SCORES
STR 17, CON 11, DEX 15, INT 8, WIS 10, CHA 12


AC: 20 Fort: 19 Ref: 16 Will: 13
HP: 59 Surges: 9 Surge Value: 14

TRAINED SKILLS
Athletics +13, Endurance +8, Intimidate +10

UNTRAINED SKILLS
Acrobatics +6, Arcana +1, Bluff +3, Diplomacy +3, Dungeoneering +2, Heal +2, History +1, Insight +2, Nature +2, Perception +2, Religion +1, Stealth +8, Streetwise +3, Thievery +6

POWERS
Basic Attack: Melee Basic Attack
Basic Attack: Ranged Basic Attack
Ironwrought Attack: Inevitable Strike
Bugbear Racial Power: Predatory Eye
Multiple Class Attack: Power Strike
Fighter Utility: Battle Wrath
Fighter Utility: Berserker's Charge
Fighter Utility 2: Single Out
Fighter Attack 3: Rain of Blows

FEATS
Level 1: Mark of Storm
Level 2: Flail Expertise
Level 4: Martial Cross-Training

ITEMS
Iron Armbands of Power (heroic tier) x1
Badge of the Berserker +1
Longbow (Large)
Freezing Arrow +1
Firestorm Arrow +1
Potion of Healing
Potion of Resistance (heroic tier)
Arrows
Flask (empty)
Flotation bladder
Climber's Kit
Backpack (empty)
Hempen Rope (50 ft.)
Listening Cone
Crowbar
Lightning Heavy flail (Large) +1
Scale Armor of Cleansing +1 x1
====== End ======
```

Cleric is heal heavy, Paladin is basic, a scout and scoundrel. Havent played with this group yet, so its hard to opine on on overall party strategy. But I would like to charge in, knock prone, shift out. Then on next turn, move into charging range and charge again. I can do this without knocking prone, but i figured it would help promoate CA for our scoundrel and being able to provide him with sneak attack would be more beneficial than my extra 1d8+3

Answer (score 3):

OK, this is a melee heavy party outside of the cleric.

The scout, scoundrel and Paladin will likely always want to be in melee range (or just out in the case of the Scoundrel).

You and the Scout will be trying to charge someone every round. Your responsibility should be to remain in melee for the scoundrel's chosen target so the he has someone to flank with. The scout should do his best to remain out of melee range after his turn.

If Themes are active, I highly recommend the Guardian theme as you're the toughest of the strikers so taking a hit/encounter for the Scout or Scoundrel is a good trade.

I think you've missed the best opportunity here though. **Surprising Charge, with a Gouge.** (feats: Weapon Prof: Gouge, Weapon Expertise: Two-handed Weapon, Surprising Charge), grab a Vanguard Gouge and you're doing 5d8 + str + dex + 6 on every charge you make with CA (which is super easy to get here). Plus you'll also qualify for Headsman's chop which you can pick up at 6. Assuming 20 str and 18 dex that makes your to hit and damage with CA:

```
str  1/2 lev  exp  stance  charging  CA  mag weap  prof weapon talent
 5 +   2    +  1 +    2  +  1      +  2    + 1   +   2  +   1         = 17
```

And damage that looks like

```
weapon      sup charge     van  dex  str   arms   exp  slayer magic weapon
  2d8[B1]  + 2d8[B1]   +   1d8   4 +  5   + 2     + 1   + 2       +1
```

That's 5d8 (four of them brutal) and +15 static damage at L5 for 39.5 per hit. With a 90% hit chance that's 35.7 damage per charge (includes crit damage).

Comment: Question on surprising charge, since it states extra 1[W], do you add any modifiers such as item bonuses?

Comment: @ToddTabacco no, those only get added the one time. This thing's damage is already verging on the silly range.

Answer (score 0):

**Optimize for damage**

Assuming your Ranger(scout) party member built right he took aspect of the ram, a stance which allows him to prone an enemy as a free action after a successful charge attack. Since the scout is an essential class much like yourself he should be knocking 1 enemy prove almost every round. The scoundrel should be able to work with that or generate his own CA via flanking or other abilities.

If you used axes or swords instead of flails I would suggest picking up headsman's chop (feat) for an extra 5 damage vs prone enemies.

Comment: I just checked and he does have Aspect of the Charging Ram.  You think since he has that I should dump my proning ability and go for more damage or we should both be charging and proning?

Comment: @ToddTabacco yes forget about proning. Its not something your class does particularly well compared to a regular fighter or a knight. Having 1 more enemy prone is not that much of an advantage vs. killing an enemy faster so unless you're going to pickup a defender or a controller class don't worry about it.